# Linphone Не компилиться под windows

Tags: c, windows, mingw, voip, компиляция

1. Windows
2. mingw

Есть замечательная [библиотека](http://linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone/overview) для работы с SIP/VoIP
И есть у неё [git](http://git%20clone%20git://git.linphone.org/linphone.git%20--recursive), так вот, проблема следующего характера - 
Библиотека (именно библиотека, а не софтфон) не собирается ни на венде, ни на Debiane. При сборке linphone вылазит ошибка "CouLd not find bctoolbox"

Хорошо думаю я, и иду компилять bctoolbox и получаю ошибку "BCUnit not find".
"Ok" говорю я ему, вытягиваю из репы BCUnit и начинаю компилять его. Он компилится без ошибок. Иду снова в папку bctoolbox и делаю `./configure`
Получаю ошибку "BCUnit/BCUnit.h" not found"

В чём проблема и как мне всё же собрать библиотеку?

Comment: Надо вначале установить библиотеку, потом компилировать следующую. И так далее до слов "да пошёл он на... этот опенсорс!".